# Vector push_back Array of doubles

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

So I got a vector of multidimensional arrays of doubles.
The vector is created with this code

```
std::vector<std::array<double, 3>> matrix;
```

After this the vector is filled with the xy coordinates of points and other informations, and sorted. This is needed so I become the outer shape of a given 2d model. To close the outer shape of the model, I have to copy the informations of the first point to the end of the vector.
I know, if I have a vector of vectors I could use code like this.

```
matrix.push_back(std::vector<double>(3, 0));
int p = matrix.size()-1;        
matrix[p][0]=matrix[0][0];
matrix[p][1]=matrix[0][1];
matrix[p][2]=matrix[0][2];
```

Since I'm using a vector of arrays, this seems to be wrong. I tried to use this code slightly modified.

```
matrix.push_back(std::array<double, 3>);
```

But here I get the error message:

> class: std::array Error: type name is not allowed

I'm using VisualStudio 2012. Can somebody tell me, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You can't insert a `std::vector<double>` object into a vector of `std::array<double, 3>`. You can use something like this instead: `matrix.push_back({1, 2, 3});`

Comment: You don't have to add the first point at the end of the polygon.  This is rather error-prone.  It is better to have a "closed polygon" flag in your close so you know that after the last point, you need an extra line to the first point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `std::array` is copyable, so if you want to copy the first item to the end just say:

```
matrix.push_back(matrix[0]);
```

As for why you're getting the error, it's because you're passing the name of a type to `push_back` rather than an object.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. With your code the program can be compiled but, when I start the software I get the message: "Expression: vector subscript out of range." As soon as I comment the line of code, everything works.

Comment: @user3794592 - you'll need to add code to check that there's actually something in the array before you try to copy it.

Answer (score 0):

The line `matrix.push_back(std::array<double, 3>);` is bad syntax. You just have a type name in the brackets, instead of an object.

As an example, `matrix.push_back(std::array<double, 3>{1.0, 2.0, 3.0});` would be valid.